# unable to build release apk in android studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0-alpha04.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Users/preet/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/preet/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/preet/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/preet/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/preet/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/preet/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.jar
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.pom
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.jar
>            https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.pom
>            https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.jar
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.pom
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0-alpha04/lint-gradle-26.1.0-alpha04.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :app

Comment: Please add more details (Stack Overflow requires a Minimum Verifiable Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How can we solve your problem with only an error code?

Answer (score 1):

Check your **build.gradle** file, it looks like some of the required repositories are missed.

for example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```